# How to make Json database distinct for each server?

Tags: discord.py

So i made a code for warns system, in server it works without issue but the warns are being transferred over to each of the server the bot is in, Plz advise how to make warns distinct for each server

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if reason==None:
    reason="Defying a Supreme Power"
  else:
    reason = ' '.join(reason)
    for current_user in Warnlog['user']:
      if current_user['name'] == user.name:
        current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
        break
    else:
      Warnlog['user'].append({
        'name':user.name,
        'reasons': [reasons,]
      })
    with open('Warnlog.json','w+') as f:
      json.dump(Warnlog,f)
    a=discord.Embed(title="Warned",color=0x800000)
    a.add_field(name=f"{user.name} has been warned",value=f" **Reason:-** {reason}")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=a)  

@Client.command(manage_channels = True)
async def infractions(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in Warnlog['user']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      Op=discord.Embed(title=f"**Warn list for {user.name}**",inline=True)
      Op.add_field(name="No. Of Warns Recived", value=f"{len(current_user['reasons'])}",inline=True)
      Op.add_field(name='Warns', value=f"{','.join(current_user['reasons'])}\n",inline=False)
      Op.set_thumbnail(url=f'{user.avatar_url}')
      await ctx.send(embed=Op)
      break
  else:
    Io=discord.Embed(title="**Warns**",description=f"{user.name} hasn't commited a Warnable action(YET)")
    await ctx.send(embed=Io)  ```
````

Comment: Edit i forgot to add this part
```with open('Warnlog.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    Warnlog = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    Warnlog = {}
    Warnlog['user'] = []```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the structure of your json from `Warnlog[user]` to `Warnlog[ctx.guild.id][user]`. You can just change this in your code everywhere you are using `Warnlog[user]`, but you have to reset the json database.